# Why does the third element in this grid align to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, grid

[CodenPen link](https://codepen.io/codefined/pen/gObwZgm)

```
<body>
  <container>
    <nav></nav>
    <main>
      <section></section>
      <section></section>
      <section></section>
      <section></section>
      ...
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </container>
</body>
```

```
container {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;

    min-height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
}
```

Images below have an extra `border-style: dashed` attached to 'section' elements.  With one or two sections in the `main` group everything is fine:

[image]
[image]

With three or more elements however, they go to the bottom of the screen:

[image]
[image]

When you get enough items on the screen to fill up one single view, it seems to work again:

[image]

Comment: can you share it on codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: @ShahryarMohajer https://codepen.io/codefined/pen/gObwZgm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flex-box to structure the page instead of grid. It's more flexible and responsive, which is why bootstrap uses and recommends it. Also there is no 
`<container></container>` element.

```css
body {
 background-color: red;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
} 

nav {
 background-color: yellow;
 width: 100%;    
}

main {
 background-color: pink;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 flex-grow: 1;
 width: 100%;
}


footer {
 background-color: blue;
 width: 100%;
}

.container {
    background-color: cyan;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>nav bar</nav>
    <main>
      <section>section 1</section>
      <section>section 2</section>
      <section>section 3</section>
      <section>section 4</section>
    </main>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If I make `container` and `main` to be flexbox instead of grid, my `footer` no longer stays at the bottom of the page.  Is there a way to do that with flexbox?

Comment: For future people, I set `nav` and `footer` to `flex-grow` 0 so that they didn't grow at all based on size of the page.  But this answer worked perfectly, thanks :).  Flex does seem easier than grid.

Comment: Cleaned up answer some more.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that the last element is aligned to the bottom of the page, it's that the grid you defined makes it so that the first "row" of the grid gets the height of its content, the second "row" was set to 1fr ( 1fr stands for 1 fraction, 1 fraction of the available space ), the third "row" was again set to auto. From the fourth element and above there are no "row" rules so by default it is set to auto.

Lets take your third image to account.
Because your  tag has a css rule of "grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;"
The first and third ( and every element after the third  tag ) will have auto height, height that is set by the content of the  tag.
Now the second element, because of the 1fr rule will always take the remaining available space.
That is why you can see by your examples that not the last element "sticks" to the bottom, but the second element always takes the remaining available space.

Hope this helps =].
Go easy on me, this is my first answer, would appreciate all feedback.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, I honestly had no idea how the grid solution was working, I thought the `auto 1fr auto` meant that the first and last elements had automatic sizing and the others all took up their normal size, that makes much more sense now.  I've opted to switch to `flexbox` now, as that seems easier to not shoot yourself in the foot over.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you are asking.  You want the first two sections on the top on the page next to each other and then what?

depending on how you want to display the grid change the css for grid-template-rows. although I would personally use flexbox as suggested

```css
container {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

main {
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: relative;

    min-height: 100%; 
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 25px auto    ;
    grid-template-columns: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <container>
    <nav style="background-Color:lightBlue;height:10px"></nav>
    <main style="background-Color:pink;height:200px">
      <section style="background-Color:purple;height:25px;margin:0 40px"></section>
      <section style="background-Color:green;height:25px;margin:0 40px"></section>
      <section style="background-Color:purple;height:25px;margin:0 40px"></section>
      <section style="background-Color:green;height:25px;margin:0 40px"></section>
      
    </main>
    <footer style="background-color:blue;height:10px"></footer>
  </container>
</body>
```

Comment: I seem to have the same thing with this as I do with the `flexbox` solution, the `footer` element no longer stays at the bottom of the page if the content isn't large enough to fill up the entire page.  Also, the sections inside of it position themselves to take up the full space of a page, instead I would like them to be top-aligned as in the current solution (for, at least, the top two sections).